# Why does this return ‘yup’?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I’m puzzled why this prints ‘yup’… neither ‘z’ or ‘d’ is in ‘bba’…

```
x = 'bba'
if 'z' or 'd' in x:
    print('yup')
else:
    print( 'nope
```

——————
If I just write a simple check it prints ‘nope’.. which was expected.

```
x = 'bba'
if 'z' in x:
    print('yup')
else:
    print( 'nope’)
```

Comment: Hint: Try running `'a' or 'b'` at the Python prompt and see what it returns.

Comment: Once you've done that, try running `'a' or 'b' in [1,2,3]`, and `'b' in [1,2,3]`, and `'a' or False`. The output of those four statements should make what you're seeing make intuitive sense.

Comment: `if 'z' or 'd' in x` really means `if ('z') or ('d' in x)`.